How to calculate long term absence DAX
I have a dataset where I have various activities with the primary two in question is paid hours and absence hours.
We measure long term absence as five days of absence in a row, in which all dates from the start to end of absence period is to be marked as LTA.
Am not familiar enough with DAX to work out a calculation for this if it was python testing would be fine but in work we primarily deal with DAX and power pivot.
Paid hours shows shifts scheduled for, absence shows hours of absence in addition to paid hours.
How do I go about this?
Filtered one agent with LTA Example :

Example of non LTA i.e. short term absence :

Example Dataset :

Have attempted this before with potential If statements but given the length of absence can vary it is not appropriate without something that loops which I cannot find within excel.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/78537290/21688343 and see if that helps. Otherwise update your question with your data table in markdown format.

what's the expected output based on the example dataset you provided?

The output would ideally be a True/False column based if it qualifies as long term absence.

@SamNseir This seems like the sort of function I require will try tomorrow when I have more time for it I would submit the data set but the size of the set is sat at 86,000 rows currently.
